# MVC 5 Form Submit event.preventDefault() Html DisplayFor won't render

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC 5, Razor and am very puzzled on this problem. I'm creating a JQuery draggable/droppable page where users can drag an item from an "Available Item" unordered list over to a "Selected Item" unordered list.

When an item is dropped, I use javascript to add a list item to the ul. When the form's submit button is clicked and the form is submitted, I stop the default submission from taking place by calling the event.preventDefault() method. I then loop through all the id's of the selected items, put them into an array, and then post them to the controller method. All this works well.

If an error occurs, I want to render the error message at the top of the response page in a new table column. It does not get rendered (it's not in the page source). It took awhile to figure out but it looks like it's the event.preventDefault() method that causes it -- if I take that out, it shows the error message fine but of course the controller method is called twice.

Any help is greatly appreciated as to why that happens.

UPDATE: I have added code that should compile and reproduce the issue:
- run it, and leave the "Enter Data Set Name:" textbox empty (which is an error)
- click "Add Data Set" button and you won't see any error message.
- Comment out event.preventDefault() in the form submit javascript function
- run it, doing the same thing and you will see the error message (in red font).

Class:

```
public class DataSourceField
{       
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class DataSetMaintModel : ModelBase
{
    public int[] InsertSelFields { get; set; }
    public List<DataSourceField> AvailColumnList { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMsg { get; set; }
    public string DataSetNameInsert { get; set; }

    public DataSetMaintModel()
    { }

}
```

Razor View:

```
@using TOTestMgmt
@model TOTestMgmt.Models.DataSetMaintModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CM Lot Search";
}

@MvcHtmlString.Create("<table border=\"1\" style=\"margin:20px;\">")
@MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr><td style=\"width:45px;\" class=\"MainLayoutHeader\">")
@MvcHtmlString.Create("Data&nbsp;Set&nbsp;Maintenance</td>")

@if (Model != null && Model.ExceptionMsg != null)
{
    <td class="ErrorMsg" style="padding-left:15px; padding-top:8px;" colspan="4">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ExceptionMsg)
   </td>
}

@MvcHtmlString.Create("</tr>")   

@MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr><td colspan=\"3\" class=\"LayoutColumn\" style=\"width:")

@MvcHtmlString.Create("vertical-align:top; padding-top:6px;\">")
@MvcHtmlString.Create("<div class=\"OuterDivThinBorder\">")
@MvcHtmlString.Create("<table border=\"1\" class=\"ContentTable\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\" height=\"400px\" width=\"100%\">")
@MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr height=\"30px\"><td class=\"SmallHeaderColor\" colspan=\"2\">")

@MvcHtmlString.Create("<b>Add&nbsp;New&nbsp;Data&nbsp;Set</b></td></tr>")

@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertDataSet", "DataSetMaint", FormMethod.Post))
{           
if (Model != null)
{
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr height=\"25px\"><td class=\"LeftIndent\" style=\"padding-top:8px; vertical-align: top; width:30%;\" >")
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("Enter&nbsp;Data&nbsp;Set&nbsp;Name:<br>")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataSetNameInsert, new { @style = "width:97%;", @class = "LeftIndent" })
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("</td>")
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:15px; vertical-align:bottom; width:30%;\">")
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("<input class=\"GreyButton\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Data Set\" name=\"InsertDataSetSubmit\"/></td></tr>")
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr height=\"25px\"><td style=\"padding-top:3px;\" class=\"LeftIndent\" width=\"90px\" colspan=\"3\">")

    @MvcHtmlString.Create("Available Fields</td></tr>")

    @MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr height=\"300px\"><td style=\"vertical-align:top;\" class=\"LeftIndent\">")

    <div id="AvailColsDiv">
        <ul style="margin-left:-35px;">                
            @foreach (DataSourceField item in Model.AvailColumnList)
            {
                <li class="dragclass" id="@item.Id" title="@item.Text">@item.Text</li>
            }                
        </ul>
    </div>

    @MvcHtmlString.Create("</td><td style=\"vertical-align:top; width:40%;\" class=\"LeftIndent\">")

    <div id="SelectedColsDiv">
        <ul style="margin-left:-20px;">
            @*<li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>*@
        </ul>
    </div>

    @MvcHtmlString.Create("</td></tr>")
    }
  }

    @MvcHtmlString.Create("</table></div></td></tr></table>")

  @section JavaScript {
<script src="~/Scripts/MyJavaScript.js"></script>
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("#AvailColsDiv li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    refreshPositions: true
});
$("#SelectedColsDiv").droppable({
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();

        $('<li class="dropclass droplistitem" id="' + id + '" title="' + ui.draggable.text() + '"></li>').text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});
});

$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
//Stop the default submission
event.preventDefault();

var ids = [];
$('.droplistitem').each(function (index, value) {
    var id = $(value).prop('id');
    ids.push(id);
});

$.post(
    '/DataSetMaint/InsertDataSet',
  {
      requestModel: {
          InsertSelFields: ids,
          DataSetNameInsert: $('#DataSetNameAdd').val()
      },
      Ids: ids
  }
 );
});
```

Controller Method:

```
public class DataSetMaintController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DataSetMaintAdd(int Id = 1, string successMsg = null)
    {
        DataSetMaintModel responseModel = null;

        try
        {
            responseModel = new DataSetMaintModel();
            responseModel.AvailColumnList = PopulateAvailList();                
            return View(responseModel);
        }            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseModel.ExceptionMsg = ex.Message;               
            return View("DataSetMaintAdd", responseModel);
        }
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertDataSet(DataSetMaintModel requestModel, int[] Ids) 
    {
        DataSetMaintModel responseModel = new DataSetMaintModel();

        try
        {
            //Validate required values
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestModel.DataSetNameInsert))
            {
                responseModel.AvailColumnList = PopulateAvailList(); 
                throw new Exception("Please Enter Data Set Name");
            }

            responseModel.DataSetNameInsert = requestModel.DataSetNameInsert;
            responseModel.AvailColumnList = PopulateAvailList(); 

            return View("DataSetMaintAdd", responseModel);     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            ModelState.Remove("ExceptionMsg");               
            responseModel.ExceptionMsg = ex.Message;         
            return View("DataSetMaintAdd", responseModel);                
        }
    }

   public List<DataSourceField> PopulateAvailList()
   {
       List<DataSourceField> availColumnList = new List<DataSourceField>();

       DataSourceField field = new DataSourceField { Id = 1, Text = "Item 1" };
       availColumnList.Add(field);

       field = new DataSourceField { Id = 2, Text = "Item 2" };
       availColumnList.Add(field);

       return availColumnList;
   }
}
```

CSS:

```
#AvailColsDiv {  
float: left;
background-color: #E5E4E2;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: visible;
width: 290px;   
height: 450px;  
margin: 5px; 
overflow-y: scroll; 
overflow-x: hidden;
}

#AvailColsDiv ul{
height: 750px;
float: left;
}

#SelectedColsDiv { 
float:left;
background-color: #E5E4E2;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow:visible;
width: 290px;   
height: 450px;  
margin: 5px; 
max-height: 450px;
overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.dragclass {
background-color: #ffff99;
border: 1px solid Black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
width: 220px;
list-style-type:none;
}

.dropclass {    
background-color: #ffff99;
border: 1px solid Black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
width: 220px;
list-style-type:none;     
}

#AvailColsDiv li, #SelectedColsDiv li {
cursor: pointer;
}

.ErrorMsg {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
color: red;
}
```

Comment: You making an ajax call. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. It will never redirect so `return RedirectToAction(...)` is pointless. And the code in your POST method wont even compile.

Comment: Please see my updated code and the directions above it which should compile and reproduce the issue. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your still making an ajax call and you don't do anything with the view that you return. What is the point of this. Make a normal submit and if there is an error, then add a `ModelState` error and return the view so its displayed, other wise redirect. (and for you drap/drop, just add a hidden inputs with `name="Ids"` to bind to the parameter. And what is all that `@MvcHtmlString.Create(...)` code for? - just add the html elements directly into the view.

Comment: Its hard to image where you got the idea for this code. Sorry to be harsh, but everything your doing is bad practice. I suggest you study [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AiFzIf) for how to implement this.

Comment: I followed your fiddle and it works well now. Much appreciated! I learned a lot from it and from your comments also.